# How to link to wagtail routablepage from outside cms?

Tags: python, django

Currently, I'm trying to integrate django wagtail with existing project, I use wagtail for blog and then I create routablepage within the wagtail.

How can I reverse to that page from my django index page ?

Comment: Are you asking how to set up the model structure?  If so, it would be helpful if you would post the relevant parts of your models.py file.

Comment: it's more into how can i use routable url for page outside the wagtail cms

But right now i'm using template tags to render routable page url and passing the parameter i need from that templatetags